# Using Message Boxes in Windows 7 style

Tags: windows, user-interface, windows-7, dialog

After reading the MSDN article about proper user interface here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa974176.aspx

I want to modify the message boxes I use in my applications to reflect those guidelines (for example, have the Main Instructions in a larger font, better named Buttons, etc...).

My question is, is there an API that allows you to easily build those kind of message boxes (a la user32\MessageBox()), or do you actually have to build your own message boxes which follow the guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly you just get that (try it and see!) when you use MessageBox or whatever wrapper applies in the language you're using (you didn't say.) There is also Task Based Dialog which goes well beyond the yes/no/cancel world of message box. There is a Win32 API for that if you're in C++, and the Windows API Code Pack has a wrapper if you're in C# or VB.NET.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the same style. However, there is no option to custom name the buttons, or to set a part of the text in the larger font used as the Main Instruction.

I am not using any wrapper. I only have access to the Win32 APIs.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760441(v=VS.85).aspx has a picture of a task dialog and links to the APIs you can call.